# Как сделать проверку на вращение в Unity 3D?

Tags: c#, unity3d, if, условия, rotation

Есть объект который при нажатии клавиши D поворачивается 90 градусов.

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 90f, 0f);
```

Как добавить ещё одно условие с проверкой после нажатия D "повернут ли объект на 90 градусов?"

Если не повернут - повернуть, а если повернут то оставить так как есть?

Comment: А сейчас как работает?

Comment: Так же, мне нужно это условие что бы я мог и дальше добавлять другие условия после проверки.
Просто не могу понять как проверить объект < или > 90 градусов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно проверять просто через [Transform.eulerAngles](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html)

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
{
    if (transform.eulerAngles.y != 90)
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 90f, 0f);
    }
}
```